# Question on the proof of Vitali-Caratheodory Theorem in Rudin's R&CA

Tags: real-analysis

[Page 56](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkDie.png),[Page 57](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdEGn.png) Sorry, my question may be a bit naive.

On page 56 and 57 of Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis (see the attached snapshots), why did Rudin use an infinite sequence to express $v$, while express $u$ by a finite sequence only upto $N$？

I think I understand the $v$'s. It sounds reasonable. But did Rudin choose $N$ only to satisfy the $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ in equation (6)?

Or why don't we apply both infinite forms as follows:
$$v-u=\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}c_i(\chi_{V_i}-\chi_{K_i})\leq\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}c_i\frac{\epsilon}{c_{i}2^{i}}\leq\epsilon$$

Here I modify $\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+1}}$ in the equation (4) to $\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i}}$. It seems to be more straightforward than dividing a sequence into two parts $\sum^N_{i=1}$ and $\sum^{\infty}_{N+1}$.

This sort of technique appears in many textbooks. I always have the doubt that why authors didn't show the $\epsilon$-related inequality in a single one line like above, instead they always did it like Rudin's, a bit more steps. I want to know the reason for decomposing to $\sum^N_{i=1}$ and $\sum^{\infty}_{N+1}$. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The partial sums for the series defining $v$ are all lower semicontinuous, since they're finite *positive* linear combinations of lower semicontinuous functions (characteristic functions of open sets). Hence $v$, their supremum, is lower semicontinuous.

The partial sums for $u$ are likewise finite positive linear combinations of upper semicontinuous functions (characteristic functions of closed sets), hence upper semicontinuous. But their supremum might not be upper semicontinuous. There is no analogy here with what happens for *lower* semicontinuous functions.